# Epson Perfection V33 not working after installing Trusty Tahr 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, scanner, epson

Already checked this link: [Epson V33 Perfection not working with 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492477/epson-v33-perfection-not-working-with-14-04)

It did not answer my problem.  I followed the advice given and it still XSane will still not launch.  Unlike the poster of the previous question, not even "Simple Scan" works.  I get this error from XSane:

Failed to open device 'epkowa:interpreter:006:007': Error during device I/O.

Comment: I thought for sure I found the answer on Epson's FAQ site.  I added myself to the "scanner" group and rebooted, but I got the same result.  The scanner seems to fire up, but then after a few minutes it goes quiet and that same pop-up message appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of the drivers from Epson seem to work.  XSANE still doesn't work, but now the ISCAN program does, and that's all I need.